# XML code confusion. Keep getting " '(' required to start ATTLIST enumeration " Not sure how to fix

Tags: xml, debugging, dtd

I am a student in college, and I'm having trouble with this code file. I would ask the teacher or other classmates, but no one seems to be responding to my code trouble on BlackBoard. So I hope anyone here could help!

The instruction states "For the `versionDate` element, an optional `surveyDate` attribute containing the date of the survey". I'm not entirely sure what it means, but I tried  "`<!ATTLIST versionDate surveyDate #IMPLIED>`", but the error code above came up. The only line of text which has "`surveyDate`" in it is this one:

```
<versionDate surveyDate=">1849"<1968/versionDate>
```

I tried to remove that line to see if it was how I wrote it, but then I received the error code "`ATTLIST: no name for Attribute`", which I believe all my code does have a name for. Could anyone help?

If it helps the entire element and attlist code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE products
[
    <!ELEMENT product (product+)>

    <!ELEMENT product (name, versionDate, desc, isbn?, price?)>

    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST name pid ID #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST name category (historical |state |parks ) #REQUIRED>


    <!ELEMENT versionDate (#PCDATA)>


    <!ELEMENT desc (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST price format (flat |raised ) "flat" #IMPLIED> <!-- format default is flat. -->
    <!ATTLIST price media (paper | electronic)>
]>
```

Comment: Forgot to add "<ATTLIST versionDate surveyDate #IMPLIED>" right below the "<!ELEMENT versionDate (#PCDATA)>" in the full code

Comment: Then add that to your question. You can [edit] your question any time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 3 issues:

1. You've declared `product` twice. Based on the doctype declaration, the first element declaration should be for `products` (plural).
2. In the attribute declaration for the `format` attribute of the `price` element, you have an [enumeration](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Enumeration) with the values "flat" and "raised" and a default value of "flat". You also have `#IMPLIED` which is invalid if you have a default value. You should remove `#IMPLIED`.
3. In the attribute declaration for the `media` attribute of the `price` element, you have an enumeration but don't have a default value, `#IMPLIED`, or `#REQUIRED`. Do **one** of these:

   - Add a default value (that matches a value in the enumeration)
   - Add `#IMPLIED`
   - Add `#REQUIRED`

Also, you can combine the `ATTLIST` declarations for an element. It makes it a little easier to read.

One last thing, if this an external DTD, you probably don't need the doctype declaration in the DTD file. The doctype should be in the XML instance that is referencing the DTD. If the XML and DTD are all in one file, ignore this comment. ([This section of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) might help understanding the doctype declaration and DTD (prolog).)

Example...

```
<!DOCTYPE products [
<!ELEMENT products (product+)>

<!ELEMENT product (name, versionDate, desc, isbn?, price?)>

<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST name 
    pid ID #REQUIRED
    category (historical|state|parks) #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT versionDate (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST versionDate 
    surveyDate CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT desc (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST price 
    format (flat|raised) "flat"
    media  (paper|electronic) #REQUIRED>
]>
```

**EDIT:** I also added the attribute declaration for the `surveyDate` attribute on the `versionDate` element. This was missing the attribute type. ([See here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttlistDecl) for more information.)

Your XML example of the `versionDate` element is also incorrect; it's not [well-formed](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed). It should look like this:

```
<versionDate surveyDate="1849">1968</versionDate>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :] Thanks so much for the assistance! It's been stressing me for a while. A few things to note though...

I'm not entirely sure why "<!ATTLIST price 
    format (flat|raised) "flat"
    media  (paper|electronic) #REQUIRED>" works while having it split up like I did, being coded the same and both being required would not work. 

and for the not well formed versionDate surveyDate code was my stress/tired mistake of typing it out. Thank you again for helping me!